# plsql array in and out parameter without database change with jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, jdbc, plsql

I am using jdbctemplate for database and need to pass array of string and number to a anonymous procedure , DB changes are not allow.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your plsql block but you can follow this approach using jdbc. Try and see this works  and hope this will be helpful, otherwise provide feedback.

```
    String myArray[] = { "black", "blue", "orange", "red" };
    ArrayDescriptor des = 
        ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("ARRAY_TYPE", conn);
    // presume that you have created ARRAY_TYPE in your schema
    ARRAY array = new ARRAY(des, conn, myArray);
    CallableStatement cst = conn.prepareCall("call yourproc(?,?)");
    cst.setArray(1, array);
    cst.registerOutParameter(2, 
                             Types.INTEGER); // presume that second param is out
    cst.execute();
```